# how to define an example of ODE that represents an undamped forced oscillator whose time evolution is described by beats

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, variable

I am a newbie in Mathematica and I really don't know how to define an example of ODE that represents an undamped forced oscillator

Comment: Please can you give me some advice? How to start to solve this problem

Comment: Do you know the appropriate ODE?  If so, add it to your question.

Comment: The problems ask defining any ODE with undamped forced oscillator

Comment: I know at the beginning it is hard to pose a good question, it will be easier with experience. Well, what do you mean by "beats". Beats appear when you have several coupled oscillators, but you speak of one oscillator. And what about the driving force?

Answer (score 5):

Not really a mathematica problem but here is something to get you going in the Wolfram Language.

```
eqn = x''[t] + (2 π 100)^2 x[t] == f[t];
ic = {x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0};
f[t_] := Sin[110 2 π t];
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eqn}, ic], {x}, {t, 0, 0.2}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 0.2}]
```

[image: Plot from oscillator]

Here I have made an oscillator with a natural frequency of 100 Hz and then applied a force with a frequency of 110 Hz.

The equation you are after is called eqn. The initial conditions are ic and the force has been defined as f[t].

You should be able to copy and paste that into `Mathematica` and get the plot I have shown.

Good luck